# This value is deprecated, (Android Studio)

Tags: android

This is the error i get:

[image]

I started off with an API level of 23, but then after research, added this string in the gradle.build file,

```
compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
```

This fixed, or rather, resolved many symbols that I was having issues with. But now, there is still some code that is striken through, such as,

```
Httpparams
```

and

```
HttpConnectionParams
```

as can be seen in the above linked picture.

This isn't letting me reach out to my server to log, send, update and retrieve data.

Also, it's probably why the app keeps crashing when certain buttons are clicked, which is also a big issue. The app never crashed until the Http strings were implemented.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Deprecations come in the form of Warnings, not Errors.

Answer (score 1):

**According to the Android documentation**

> **Apache HTTP Client Removal** 
>   This preview removes support for the Apache
>   HTTP client. If your app is using this client and targets Android 2.3
>   (API level 9) or higher, use the [HttpURLConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class instead. This
>   API is more efficient because it reduces network use through
>   transparent compression and response caching, and minimizes power
>   consumption.

See Here https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html